# how to specify username and password for jconsole from command line?

Tags: java, jconsole

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JConsole command line credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343364/jconsole-command-line-credentials)

Is there a way to specify username and password for jconsole from command line? I want to start jconsole completely from command line because the host name is too long (service:jmx:rmi://serveraddress:8010/jndi/rmi://serveraddress:8000/jmxrmi) and I can't remember them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a bat file with all the parameters (or) command line like below. Something like this.

```
jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=value
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=value
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=value
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=value
```

Note: This is example, actual parameters you need should be substituted instead of these.

Comment: i am using rmi to connect to the remove server. Is ssl needed?

Comment: No, As I said those are example parameters I have used in my local. For you instead of ssl, use whatever key/values required there.